# How to make the text in new line

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I have question how to make text that print in new line without using `System.out.println();` I want them in 1 line:

```
System.out.print("Running a java application");
System.out.println("...Finished");
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%s %s%n", "Running a java application", "...Finished");`

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What is your intended output?

Answer (score 2):

Two very common ways to print a newline (without using `println()`) are:

```
System.out.print("\n")
```

and

```
System.out.printf("%n")
```

You, can, of course, print other things along with that.  The following <s>are all equivalent</s> all produce equivalent output on systems where the line-break is 'newline':

```
System.out.print("Running a java application"); System.out.println("...Finished");

System.out.print("Running a java application...Finished\n");
System.out.print("Running a java application...Finished" + "\n");
System.out.printf("Running a java application...Finished%n");
System.out.printf("%s%n", "Running a java application...Finished");
```

**EDIT 1 :** Tom's comment about "similarity" is absolutely correct.  `\n` always produces a 'newline' character (`0x0A`), where `%n` produces a line break according to the platform on which the Java is running, which might or might not be a single 'newline' character.

**EDIT 2 :** Please note that it goes without saying that you can separate the two parts of the printing with code in between and achieve output like my above examples; this code produces equivalent output to the above samples (... on systems where the line-break is 'newline'):

```
System.out.printf("Running a java application");
// ... some code ...
// ... more code ...
// ... even more code ...
System.out.printf("...Finished%n");
```

but also note that this would also be true of the code in the original question:

```
System.out.print("Running a java application");
// ... some code ...
// ... more code ...
// ... even more code ...
System.out.println("...Finished");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know what you mean but I think you want them in one command , you can use "\n" to separate words into new lines in one command.

```
System.out.print("Running a java application"+"\n"+"...Finished");
```

The output will be:

```
Running a java application
...Finished
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but if you want them in spirit line using one line of code you can write this :

```
System.out.print("Running a java application" + "\n ...Finished ");
```

"+" will join 2 string together and "\n" will make the text after it in the new line

Answer (score -1):

In Java "/ n" in the print method means making a new line.
So you can write this:

```
System.out.print ("Run app java /n ... finished");
```

and the output will be

```
Run app java 
 ... finished
```